# ORA-00904: "DAYS": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

Here is the code that I have:

```
SELECT (first_name || ' ' || last_name) AS Name, hire_date, days FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE days > 365*6;
```

This is what I am supposed to do:
Create a SQL query that shows the first_name, last_name, hire_date, and the number of days that the employee has worked from the EMPLOYEES table. Use the concatenation operator to put the first_name and the last_name together in the same column in the result set with a space between the two names. Use date arithmetic to show only employees that   have worked longer than 6 years (365 * 6).

Can someone help me figure out what my error is?

Comment: Clearly, `days` is not a column in `employees`.

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear?  Does your table has column called `DAYS`?  If not then you know that's the problem.

Comment: There is a hint in the task: "Use date arithmetic...". You already know the hire date, so how would you get the number of days using that?

Comment: Obviously 365 * 6 isn't the same as six years, but if that's what your homework assignment requires then fine...

Answer (score 0):

To correct your query you need to perform date arithmetic.

```
SELECT
  (first_name || ' ' || last_name) AS name,
  hire_date,
  ROUND(sysdate - hire_date) AS days
FROM hr.employees
WHERE sysdate - hire_date > 6*365;
```

But if you analyse -> [hr schema](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/img/cncpt292.gif), you find out, that there is job_history table relevant for this task. In my opinion correct solution should be like this:

```
SELECT a1.name,
  a1.hire_date,
  a1.days
FROM
  (SELECT employees.employee_id,
    (employees.first_name || ' ' || employees.last_name) AS name,
    employees.hire_date,
    SUM(NVL(job_history.end_date, TRUNC(sysdate)) - NVL(job_history.start_date, hire_date)) AS days
  FROM hr.employees
  LEFT JOIN hr.job_history
  ON job_history.employee_id = employees.employee_id
  GROUP BY employees.employee_id,
    (employees.first_name || ' ' || employees.last_name),
    employees.hire_date
  ) a1
WHERE days > 365*6;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to put filter on the hire day instead

WHERE hire_date > sysdate - 365*6

Answer (score 0):

this will work;

```
 WHERE sysdate-hire_date >= 365*6
```